# jQuery checkbox always false

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, datatables, laravel-5.4

First off I'd like to say that I know that this question was already asked a lot of times but I can assure you that I tried using all the answers I could find but all failed.

So first off I have a [jQuery Datatable](https://datatables.net/) looking like this (I'm using laravel so that's why there's this foreach) :

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th id="head-cbx"><input type="checkbox" name="example"></th>
            <th id="head-xcode">XCODE</th>
        <tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($xcodes as $xcode)
        <tr>
            <td id="head-cbx"><input type="checkbox" class="xcode-cbx" name="xcodes[]"></td>
            <td>{{ $xcode }}</td>
        <tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The obvious objective is to have a checkbox that allows me to check / uncheck all the others.

For the jQuery part I tried the following solutions :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var headcbx = $('#head-cbx');
    headcbx.change(function(){
    if (headcbx.is(':checked')) {
            //uncheck all
        } else {
            //check all
        }
    });
}
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var headcbx = $('#head-cbx');
    headcbx.change(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            //uncheck all
        } else {
            //check all
        }
    });
}
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var headcbx = $('#head-cbx');
    headcbx.change(function(){
    if (this.is(':checked')) {
            //uncheck all
        } else {
            //check all
        }
    });
}
```

then I changed my test from

```
if (this.is(':checked'))...
```

to

```
if(this.checked)
```

and then to

```
if(this.prop('checked)
```

of course, each time I tried the variants

```
this
headcbx
$(this)
$('#head-cbx')
```

After that I tried using

```
$(document).on('change', '#head-cbx', function(){...})
```

with all the same variants that I listed above.

Anyway, I always have the same result : **false**.
So I'm beginning to get frustrated and I could use the help because I think I'm missing something obvious somewhere but I can't seem to find it...

Thanks :)

Comment: You only need this one:- `$(document).on('change', 'tr:first :checkbox', function(){
   $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is wrong, as `head-cbx` refers to `<TD>` element not `checkbox` So either change selector

```
var headcbx = $('#head-cbx :checkbox');
```

Note: `this.checked`/`$(this).is(':checked')`/`$(this).prop('checked)` would work

OR, Fix HTML

```
<th><input id="head-cbx" type="checkbox" name="example"></th>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
var headcbx = $('#head-cbx');
```

&

```
<td id="head-cbx">
```

the `id` you are ussing in event listener is of `td`, not of checkbox. So change it to something like:

```
var headcbx = $('#head-cbx :checkbox');
```

Comment: Exactly, thansk.